# Flutter: testing widgets

Tags: testing, dart, flutter

what I'm trying to test is:
the user taps a button and the snackbar is shown for five second.

Here is the scaffold with its key:

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>(debugLabel: "scaffoldState");
```

...

```
builder: (context, viewModel) => Scaffold(
              key: _scaffoldKey,
```

Then the code for the button and the snackBar:

```
child: FlatButton(key: Key('loginButton'), onPressed: () { 
 validate();
```

...

```
  validate() {
    // FormState object can be used to save, reset, and validate
    // every FormField that is a descendant of the associated Form.

    final FormState form = _formKey.currentState;

    if (form.validate()) {
      form.save();
      form.reset();

      //implementation of the snackBar:
      _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
        duration: new Duration(seconds: 5)
```

...

And I am trying to test this behaviour in this way (I'm using also Flutter redux):

```
void main(){

  final store = Store<AppState>(reducer, initialState: AppState.initialState());
  testWidgets("MaterialApp local", (WidgetTester tester) async{
    await tester.pumpWidget(new StoreProvider(
        store: store,
        child: MaterialApp(
          home: LoginView(),
        )));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    await tester.press(find.byKey(Key("loginButton")));
    expect();
```

I don't know what to put inside expect. I was trying to take the GlobalKey using find.ByKey(Key)) and to search for the debugLabel, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm trying since 2 days, but I can't find a way out.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a little late to answer this, but since it was the second result on Google when typing "Flutter test Snackbar", I will just give my two cents:

It's actually pretty simple. Don't think of the Snackbar as being something completely different only because it only resides at the bottom for a few seconds. Lastly, the Snackbar is just another Widget.

Keeping this in mind you can test it as follows:

```dart
testWidgets("MaterialApp local", (WidgetTester tester) async{
  ...
  // Test if the Snackbar appears
  expect(find.byType(SnackBar), findsOneWidget);
  // Test if it contains your text
  expect(find.text('TAPS!'), findsOneWidget);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i actually met the same condition as you did, and all i did is put a text as the content of the snackbar.

for showing the snackbar, the code i use is

```
scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("TAPS!"),));
          }, "SEE ALL", backgroundColor: Colors.red, textColor: Colors.blue)
```

and i expect to find a text with the same content as i put in, and add findsOneWidget.

`expect(find.text("TAPS!"), findsOneWidget);`